# Select Table in php mysql According table's name

Tags: php, mysql

how to show table from my database according to the name of my table? So i have some tables which is created everyday and named it according to the date, and i want to show table which is named as today on my web application. I'm using PHP and mysql in building my web application. 
Thanks so much before...

Comment: if you will show some table structure then i would be easy to help you ;)

Comment: You are not clear with your question... please properly put the scenario

Comment: i have tables which is created automatically as i uploaded it. For example table "temp_26_03_2012_16_12_03", "temp_25_03_2012_15_14_02". the name structure is temp_DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MM_SS, then i just want to show a table named with today's date(for example table "temp_26_03_2012_16_12_03").

Comment: i tried to create variable for table name, but still failed

Comment: i want to try something like this : 
$table_name = ???
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name"
how to define the $table_name?

Answer (score 0):

```
$table_name = "temp_".date('d')."k".date('m')."k".date('Y')."k".time('h')."k".time('i')."k".time('s');
```

Replace `k` with an underscore (`_`).

Comment: i've tried it, but i still got error: $temp1="temp_".date('d')."".date('m')."".date('Y')."".time('h')."".time('i')‌​."_".time('s'); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $temp1"; 
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($qry)) --->here i got the error "Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource "